# Kables isn't seeing my kable_styling attributes?

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I'm trying to spit out two [tables side by side](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#multiple-tables-side-by-side), using `knitr::kables`.

I can't figure out how to make my styles stick, though. If I run one kable, the styles work fine:

```
 kable(
      caption = "Oh look! A Caption",
      starwars %>%
        count(gender, sex) %>%
        arrange(desc(gender)) 
    ) %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```

gives me a tidy looking table:
[image]

But if I try to set two up side by side, the formatting (or `kable_styling`) gets lost:

```
knitr::kables(list(
   kable(caption = "Oh look! A Caption",
         starwars %>%
           count(gender, sex) %>%
           arrange(desc(gender))) %>%
     kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")),
   
   
   kable(caption = "Oh look! A Caption",
         starwars %>%
           count(gender, sex) %>%
           arrange(desc(gender))) %>%
     kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
 ))
```

The formatting all just evaporates:

[image]

How do I get `kable_styling` to apply to two `kables`?

Answer (score 0):

The extremely unsatisfying solution turned out to be adding a third `kable_styling()` call:

```
knitr::kables(list(
  kable(caption = "Species",
    starwars %>%
      count(species) %>%
      filter(n > 1)
    ) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")),
    kable(caption = "Homeworld",
      starwars %>%
        count(homeworld) %>%
        filter(n > 1)
    ) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
    
  )
) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```

That seems verbose, but it works.